# How can I author a XML Schema that requires one attribute to be present when another is present?

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
  <Book
    Title="Animal Farm"
    Author="George Orwell"
    />
</Books>
```

Is it possible to author a XSD for this XML file that says: If a Book element has the Title attribute, then the Author attribute must exist too? Note that I'm not asking about restrictions based on the attribute values, just the attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In XSD 1.0**, you'll have to impose that constraint at the application level.

**In XSD 1.1**, you can use `xs:assert` to impose the constraint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Title"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Author"/>
            <xs:assert test="not(@Title) or @Author"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This can also be done (perhaps more conveniently) with conditional type assignment, but either way it needs XSD 1.1.